# Minimizing population risk for logistic loss

Tags: probability, logistic, classification, binary-data

[image]

I am working on trying to show that the minimizer is equal to as given in this question. However, I can't this exact result and am starting to my book exercise has a typo. Here is my work:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you substituted $\exp(-yf(x))$ as the logistic loss, not $\log(1 + \exp(-yf(x))$. I get the expected answer when I substitute the latter term.

Feel free to take a crack at that yourself substituting in that term instead -- otherwise, I've provided the derivation below.

Let $\eta \triangleq \mathbf{Pr}[Y = 1 \mid \mathbf{x}]$, and let $z \triangleq f(\mathbf{x})$. Let $R_f$ be the expected logistic loss. Then, we need to solve $\frac{\partial R_f}{\partial z} = 0$.

We can write

$$\underset{y\mid\mathbf{x}}{\mathbb{E}}[R_f] = \underset{y\mid\mathbf{x}}{\mathbb{E}}[\log(1 + \exp(-yz))] = \log(1 + \exp(-z))\eta + \log(1 + \exp(z))(1 - \eta).$$

The derivative $\frac{\partial R_f}{\partial z}$ is

$$\frac{\partial R_f}{\partial z} = \frac{-\eta\exp(-z)}{1 + \exp(-z)} + \frac{(1 - \eta)\exp(z)}{1 + \exp(z)}.$$

Setting this to 0, we get:

$$\frac{-\eta\exp(-z)}{1 + \exp(-z)} + \frac{(1 - \eta)\exp(z)}{1 + \exp(z)} = 0$$

$$\frac{-\eta\exp(-z)}{1 + \exp(-z)} + \frac{(1 - \eta)}{1 + \exp(-z)} = 0 $$

$$-\eta\exp(-z) + (1 - \eta) = 0$$

$$ \frac{1 - \eta}{\eta} = \exp(-z)$$

from which

$$z = \log\frac{\eta}{1 - \eta} = \log\frac{\mathbf{Pr}[Y = 1 \mid \mathbf{x}]}{\mathbf{Pr}[Y = -1 \mid \mathbf{x}]}$$

is immediate.

To conclude, it suffices to show that the expected logistic loss is convex in $z$ at the above value. Plug the result into

$$\log(1 + \exp(-z))\eta + \log(1 + \exp(z))(1 - \eta),$$

yielding

$$\eta\log\left(\frac{1}{\eta}\right) + (1-\eta)\log\left(\frac{1}{1 - \eta}\right)$$

which is the sum of two neg-entropy functions for any $\eta$. The [neg-entropy function is convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3088375/negative-entropy-x-log-x-is-convex), so the result is likewise convex. $\blacksquare$

I think to be rigorous, we'd have to account for the fact that $\eta \neq 0, 1$ in the final step, but for those cases, we're left with expected logistic loss either $\log(1 + exp(-z))$ or $\log(1 + exp(z))$ which is also convex for any $z$ (you can show this graphically, or it seems pretty straightforward to use the 2nd derivative test here).